# SFML sf::Mouse::getPosition method cannot write the correct argument

Tags: c++, oop, window, sfml

My problem is that I have written this code inside `Game::HandleInput()` method but I cannot make the `sf::Mouse::getPosition()` method to get the mouse coordinates relative to window. Without argument, I don't get an error. However, ship doesn't rotate properly. I have tried `getPosition(m_window)` and `getPosition(&m_window)`. I am getting this error:

```
no instance of overloaded function "sf::Mouse::getPosition" matches the argument list
```

**EDIT: UPDATED THE WINDOW.H**

*Window.h:*

```
class Window{
    //Constructers
public:
    Window();
    Window(const std::string& l_title, const sf::Vector2u& l_size);

    ...
private:
    sf::RenderWindow m_window;
    ...
}
```

**EDIT: ADDED THE FULL CODE OF WINDOW.CPP:**

*Window.cpp:*

```
#include "Window.h"

Window::Window() {
    Setup("Window", sf::Vector2u(640, 480));
}
Window::Window(const std::string& l_title, const sf::Vector2u& l_size) {
    Setup(l_title, l_size);
}
Window::~Window() {
    Destroy();
}

void Window::Setup(const std::string& l_title,
    const sf::Vector2u& l_size)
{
    m_windowTitle = l_title;
    m_windowSize = l_size;
    m_isFullscreen = false;
    m_isDone = false;
    Create();
}
void Window::Create() {
    auto style = (m_isFullscreen ? sf::Style::Fullscreen
        : sf::Style::Default);
    m_window.create({ m_windowSize.x, m_windowSize.y, 32 },
        m_windowTitle, style);
}
void Window::Destroy() {
    m_window.close();
}
void Window::Update() {
    sf::Event event;
    while (m_window.pollEvent(event)) {
        if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed) {
            m_isDone = true;
        }
        else if (event.type == sf::Event::KeyPressed &&
            event.key.code == sf::Keyboard::F5)
        {
            ToggleFullscreen();
        }
    }
}
void Window::ToggleFullscreen() {
    m_isFullscreen = !m_isFullscreen;
    Destroy();
    Create();
}
void Window::BeginDraw() { m_window.clear(sf::Color::Black); }
void Window::EndDraw() { m_window.display(); }

bool Window::IsDone() { return m_isDone; }
bool Window::IsFullscreen() { return m_isFullscreen; }
sf::Vector2u Window::GetWindowSize() { return m_windowSize; }

void Window::Draw(sf::Drawable& l_drawable){
    m_window.draw(l_drawable);
}
```

**EDIT: UPDATED THE GAME.H**

*Game.h:*

```
class Game{
public:
    Game();
    ~Game();
    void HandleInput();
    void Update();
    void Render();
    Window* GetWindow();
private:
    ...
    Window m_window;
    ...
}
```

**EDIT: UPDATED THE GAME.CPP**

*Game.cpp:*

```
Game::Game() : m_window("Multiplayer Space Shooter Game", sf::Vector2u(800, 600)) {
    // Setting up class members.
    m_shipText.loadFromFile("C:\\Users\\AliTeo\\Desktop\\Piksel çalışmaları\\ship_pixel2.png");
    m_ship.setTexture(m_shipText);
    m_ship.setOrigin(m_shipText.getSize().x / 2, m_shipText.getSize().y / 2);
    m_ship.setPosition(320, 240);
}
void Game::HandleInput() {
    ...
    //Get the angle between ship and mouse.
    //Error if there is an argument in getPosition()
    m_angle = atan2(sf::Mouse::getPosition().y - m_ship.getPosition().y, sf::Mouse::getPosition().x - m_ship.getPosition().x); //TO DO: getPosition(&Relative To)
    m_angle *= 180 / m_PI;
    ...
}
Window* Game::GetWindow() { return &m_window; }
```

**EDIT: ADDED THE MAIN.CPP**

*Main.cpp*

```
int main() {
    Game game;
    while (!game.GetWindow()->IsDone()) {
        game.HandleInput();
        game.Update();
        game.Render();
    }
}
```

Comment: Please post a complete reproducible example. For now voting to close as lacking such example.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Updated the code.

Comment: The updated code is still incomplete and with syntax errors unrelated to  your problem. Consider that you, as the one who is asking, **don't know enough** to decide what of your code is relevant, and what is not. If you were competent to make that decision you wouldn't have had to ask in the first place. You need to post a *complete*, and *reproducible*, example.

Comment: Just so we're clear, the `&m_window` you're trying to pass to `sf::Mouse::getPosition` is of type `Window*` not `sf::RenderWindow*` or even `sf::Window*`, right?

Comment: @Caninonos That is correct. However, m_window doesn't work too.

Comment: If that's the full code of the "window.cpp" file then there's one obvious problem: it doesn't include any headers.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Hi, This is the most relevant code I can share. Thanks you for the critisizm.

Comment: @AliTeo: You're welcome, but you'd be better off posting a complete example, as requested.

Comment: Cheers and hth. - Alf Sorry, now added.

Comment: @Cheers and hth. - Alf Updated Game.h

Comment: @AliTeo That's your problem then, `sf::Mouse::getPosition` expects a `sf::Window*` Why would your `Window*` be convertible to a `sf::Window*`? You want to pass the address of `m_window.m_window`, (the `sf::RenderWindow` inside your `Window`) not of `m_window` itself.

Comment: @Caninonos I am not sure where I should change, I have tried changing window to renderwindow, changing window.h; could you please show the mistake I made in the code?

Comment: @Caninonos: Looking at [the docs](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.0/classsf_1_1Mouse.php) all the `getPosition` overloads take reference argument, not pointer.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Indeed, I stand corrected. @AliTeo That said the problem is essentially the same. Basically, you should probably either have an accessor returning a const reference to `Window`'s `m_window` or add something like a `sf::Vector2i getMousePosition() const { return sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_window); }` method inside your `Window` class and use that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me give you what I assume is a minimal example reproducing your problem:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class MyWindow {
public:
    MyWindow()
    : m_window({800, 600, 32}, "my window title") {}

private:
    sf::RenderWindow m_window;
};

int main() {
    MyWindow window;
    sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);
}
```

This code doesn't compile (and admittedly wouldn't do anything interesting when compiled, but that's not the point). I suspect it'd give you the same error that you're currently having if you tried to compile it.

Please note that this is what we expect when we talk about a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve): this code is short, simple, exhibits the error and would compile if not because of it.

Besides, it makes the error painfully clear, and if you tried to come up with a MCVE yourself, you may have solved your problem without having to post a question here, which would certainly save you time.

---

Contrast with your code:

```
m_angle = atan2(sf::Mouse::getPosition().y - m_ship.getPosition().y
               ,sf::Mouse::getPosition().x - m_ship.getPosition().x
               );
//TO DO: getPosition(Relative To)
```

This code is legal, but you explained that it is incorrect and you wanted to turn it into something along those lines:

```
m_angle = atan2(sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_window).y - m_ship.getPosition().y
               ,sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_window).x - m_ship.getPosition().x
               );
//TO DO: getPosition(Relative To)
```

... which doesn't compile.

However, in this scope `m_window` is a `Window` not a `sf::RenderWindow`!

The problem is that you're passing a reference to an object (`MyWindow` in my example, `Window` in your case) that encapsulates a `sf::RenderWindow`, but isn't convertible to `sf::Window&` itself.
Therefore, you can't pass it to [`sf::Mouse::getPosition`](https://www.sfml-dev.org/documentation/2.4.2/classsf_1_1Mouse.php#ac368680f797b7f6e4f50b5b7928c1387) which expects either nothing or a `sf::Window&`, but certainly not a `Window&` or a `MyWindow&`.

---

There are a lot of ways of fixing this. Two of which are presented below:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class MyWindow {
public:
    MyWindow()
    : m_window({800, 600, 32}, "my window title") {}

    // you could add an accessor
    const sf::Window& getSfmlWindow() const { return m_window; }

    // you may also expose a method to get the mouse position
    // relatively to this window
    const sf::Vector2i getMousePosition() const {
        return sf::Mouse::getPosition(m_window);
    }

private:
    sf::RenderWindow m_window;
};

int main() {
    MyWindow window;
    sf::Vector2i mouse_position;
    // this won't work! window isn't convertible to sf::Window&
    // mouse_position = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window);

    // using the accessor
    mouse_position = sf::Mouse::getPosition(window.getSfmlWindow());

    // or the exposed method
    mouse_position = window.getMousePosition();
}
```